# How to delete a file from the local storage in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Actually *i want to overwrite the file* in local storage of phone but it gives me the error

```
    I/flutter ( 3835): /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.temp/files/flutter_audio_recorder_
I/flutter ( 3835): Exception: A file already exists at the path :/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.temp/files/flutter_audio_recorder_.wav
```

**so how can i delete this file first ?**

i have stored the wav file path in this variable ==>  var dirPath ;

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create this method:

```dart
Future<void> deleteFile(File file) async {
  try {
    if (await file.exists()) {
      await file.delete();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Error in getting access to the file.
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
deleteFile(File('your_file_path'));
```

Comment: yes, it works fine
Make sure you import this file 
import 'dart:io' as io;   ------ > if you import this file as io then you should write this as  var file = io.File('file_path');